Flash light frequency and rise time calculation
I know this is a very simple question for SE members. But I am always confused with these kind of things.
I was analyzing the design a hazard warning light.The spec of the light turn on off is given below.
The flashing-light frequency shall be 90+/-30 times per minute.


May I know in this case the frequency(ignoring 30) will be 60/90Hz
or 90/60Hz?

The designer used this IC to generate the PWM.

What will be the rise and fall time of the PWM coming from this IC


Hz is a unit that means per second.  The spec indicates per minute

The flashing specification means that the actual flash rate will be between 90-30 or 60 times per minute and 90+30 or 120 times per minute. Since this IC is intended to control the on time of LEDs used for visual applications (e.g. warning lights or turn signals), the rise time is not of importance because it will not affect the visual appearance of the LEDs unless it was on the order of milliseconds. This is why it is not explictly stated in the data sheet. There are formulas for calculating the turn on and turn off times of the LEDs but these are set by external components.

Thank you , frequency(ignoring 30) will be 60/90Hz or 90/60Hz?

Will the rise time and fall time of the IC cause any EMI radiated emissions

You can't ignore the 30. That is the tolerance of the rate. The nominal rate is 90. With a tolerance of 30, the actual rate can be any value from 60 to 120, For this application the rise and fall times of the IC are relatively large so EMI emissions should not be a problem.

It's not 90 Hz because Hz is cyles per second. The flash rate is 90 flashes per minute + or - 30, so between 60 and 120 flashes per minute (as Barry has said). To get Hz, you would say "90 flashes per minute" is "90 flashes per 60 seconds", so 90/60 = 3/2 = 1.5 Hz. And the tolerance boundaries are 60/60=1Hz and 120/60=2Hz. So they want flashing at 1.5 times per second, or 3 flashes every 2 seconds, but it is okay if it is anywhere from 1 flash per second to 2 flashes per second.
